# How to print exception message in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, exception

I have defined an exception in Kotlin but when I do `e.message` it prints fully qualified exception name followed by message but I want to print only exception message.

```
public final class AbcException extends Exception {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public AbcException() {
  }

  public AbcException(String message) {
    super(message);
  }

  public AbcException(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
  }

  public AbcException(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
  }
}
```

I am matching asserting it in tests and want to do

```
assertEquals(e.message, "CaseItem delete failed: item token=token1")
```

But I am doing this because it prints fully qualifies exception name too

```
assertTrue(e.message?.contains("Case Item tokens=token2 does not exist.")!!)
```

Expected
"Some message"

Actual
"exceptionClass: Some message"

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Inherit an exception, create your own "message" property and define its own toString() maybe?

Answer (score 1):

That's not Kotlin, it's Java.

The equivalent Kotlin exception would look something like this:

```kotlin
class AbcException(
    message: String? = null, 
    cause: Throwable? = null
) : Exception(message, cause) {

    // Bit odd to have an exception that wraps a cause with no message, but ok.
    constructor(cause: Throwable): this(null, cause)
}
```

The [playground](https://pl.kotl.in/_iwsYjszJ) test does as expected, only prints the message, excluding the exception type name:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    try {
        throw AbcException("Hello")    
    } catch(e: Exception) {
        println(e.message)
    }
}
```

> Hello